# Is $f(x) = xx^T$ convex?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functions, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $x = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \quad f(x) = xx^T$ be its outer product

How to assess convexity of $f(x)$?

*In other words, is $f(x) = xx^T$ convex on $\mathbb{R}^n$, if not, is it convex on $\mathbb{R}^n_{\geq 0}$...*

Comment: $x^2$ ic convex on $\mathbb{R}$ and sum of two convex functions are convex. Note that $f(x)=x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2$ is a finite sum of convex function.

Comment: @Nilan $xx^T$ is a matrix, and not a number. Maybe the problem is not written correctly

Comment: By convexity, do you mean that (1-a)f(x)+af(y)-f((1-a)x+ay) is a positive semidefinite hermitian matrix for every x,y and 0<a<1?

Comment: How is convexity defined for matrix-valued functions?

Comment: @LuizCordeiro: I think problem is correct. Here $f$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to  $\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: @celtschk I had same question, but I realized simple "matrix valued" functions such as $\text{diag}(x)$ can be trivially shown to be convex i.e. $\text{diag}(\theta x + (1-\theta)y) = \theta \text{diag}(x) + (1-\theta) \text{diag}(y)$

Comment: @Nilan $x$ is $n\times 1$, and $x^T$ is $1\times n$, so $xx^T$ is $n\times n$

Comment: @BeachedWhale: Well, $\rm diag$ is linear, and of course for linear functions you can bypass the question what "less" means in "less or equal" since "equal" applies. By definition, linear functions are the *only* functions where this works (because linearity is exactly defined through that equality).

Comment: In this sense, this function is not convex. The left hand side has rank 1 and the right has rank 2.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro: Oh.. Thank you for pointing out that. So if ti was $f(x)=x^Tx,$ then we can do something.

Comment: @celtschk Yes but that does not mean nonlinear functions such as $xx^T$  cannot be convex...in fact we do know it is convex in $\mathbb{R}$ since $x_1 x_1 = x_1^2$ is again convex, it is just not very clear if it is convex for all $n > 1$

Comment: @BeachedWhale: The point is, you first have to define what the "convex" means before you can ask whether a function fulfils that definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us say that $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow M_n$ is convex if $(1-a)f(x)+af(y)-f((1-a)x+ay)$ is a positive semidefinite hermitian matrix for every $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $0\leq a \leq1$.

Let us prove that $f(x)=xx^t$ is convex.

Notice that $(1-a)f(x)+af(y)-f((1-a)x+ay)=(x,y)A(x,y)^t$, where $A=\pmatrix{1-a & 0 \\ 0 & a}-\pmatrix{(1-a)^2 & (1-a)a \\ (1-a)a & a^2}$.

Consider $\frac{A}{(1-a)a}=\pmatrix{\frac{1}{a} & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{1-a}}-\pmatrix{\frac{1-a}{a} & 1 \\ 1 & \frac{a}{1-a}}=\pmatrix{1 & -1 \\ -1 & 1}$.

Thus, $(1-a)f(x)+af(y)-f((1-a)x+ay)=(x,y)A(x,y)^t=$

$(1-a)a(x,y)\pmatrix{1 & -1 \\ -1 & 1}(x,y)^t$,

which is positive semidefinite, whenever $0\leq a\leq 1$.

Comment: interesting, can you provide a source for that definition?

Comment: Analogous to http://press.princeton.edu/chapters/s8445.pdf, page 18

Answer (score 4):

OK, let's try a generic ansatz.

The definition of convexity is:

> A function $f:V\to W$ is convex, of vor any $x,y\in V$ and any $\lambda\in [0,1]$ we have
>   $$f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y) \le \lambda f(y) + (1-\lambda) f(y)$$

Now since we are working in linear spaces, all operations *except* the relation $\le$ on $W$ are already defined. However we can say if the definition has to make sense, $\le$ must fulfil some conditions:

- It must be a partial order.
- It must be compatible with addition, that is, for any $a,b,c\in W$ we have $$a \le b \iff a+c \le b+c.$$
- It must be compatible with scalar multiplication, that is, for any $a,b\in W$ and any $\lambda>0$, we have $$a \le b \iff \lambda a \le \lambda b.$$

Note that those conditions are already sufficient to prove that $\{x\in W|x\ge 0\}$ is a convex cone.

Further, we know that $W$ is actually a matrix space, so we have a multiplication of elements in $W$. I think a reasonable minimal condition for $\ge$ is:

- If $x=x^2$, then $x\ge 0$.

**Theorem:** Under these conditions, the function $f:x\mapsto xx^T$ is convex.

Proof:

We have
\begin{aligned}
X &:= \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda) f(y) - f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y)\\
&= \lambda xx^T + (1-\lambda) yy^T - (\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y)(\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y)^T\\
&= \left(\lambda - \lambda^2\right) xx^T  + \left((1-\lambda)-(1-\lambda)^2\right) yy^T - \lambda(1-\lambda) (xy^T + yx^T)\\
&= \lambda(1-\lambda)\left(xx^T + yy^T + xy^T +yx^T\right)\\
&= \lambda(1-\lambda)(x+y)(x+y)^T
\end{aligned}
Let's define $N=(x+y)^T(x+y)$ which clearly is a non-negative real number (it's the squared length of $x-y$). Further define
$$P = \frac{1}{N}(x+y)(x+y)^T.$$
Then
$$P^2 = \frac{1}{N^2}N(x+y)(x+y)^T = P.$$
Therefore from the definition above, $P\ge 0$. Since $N\ge 0$, it follows that $NP = (x+y)(x+y)^T\ge 0$, and since $\lambda(1-\lambda)\ge 0$ it follows that $X\ge 0$. But that's exactly the condition for convexity. $\square$